# what middleware can what controller in Laravel cannot do?

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware

while learning Laravel i came across this concept called middleware. I am wondering why we need middleware in the first place? We can implement the same logic in our controller too , then , whats the point of having middleware? what is it what we cannot do in controller and we need middleware for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple controllers and you want to apply same condition on then, rather then writing same code in multiple files(Controllers). Write code in one file(middleware) and apply on all controllers.

```
Route::middleware('checkRole')->group(function() {
    Route::get('user', 'UserController@index')
    Route::get('order', 'OrderController@index')
    Route::get('customers', 'CustomerController@index')

});
```

Comment: so what problem middlware in laravel solve?  say we want to authenticate a user. Cannot we authenticate the user using our controller before running our function?

Comment: Q: so what problem middlware in laravel solve?   
A: code redundancy.  
Q: Cannot we authenticate the user using our controller before running our function?
A: yes we do that in Controller. 
But if have 20 different controllers and we just need to check user authentication(or any condition ) we need to write same code in 20 different files we write only one file with is called Middleware and apply same code on 20 controllers :P